# Use setState in a loop

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state

react hook useState works like setState when updating the state.
That's mean asynchronously operation.
My project lean on updating state with some timeout of 2 sec.

If I have an array with 3 values and I want to make a loop and change the state every 2 sec, but the operation just take the last state like an asynchronous functions.

any idea?

```
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => setStr(arr[i]), 2000);
        }
```

Comment: I mean.. you're making all three changes at the same time, after 2 seconds. They'll likely get grouped into the same render.

Comment: This is actually kind of a tricky thing to do in React, but definitely possible. I would start by looking up how other people have made useInterval and useTimeout hooks. You'll need something like this https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-interval, but with the ability to set a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer myself.
create a promise by instantiate the promise class.
then make a function with set timout and resolve the setState function.
call it from from other function and loop in over in.

Answer (score 0):

To give some idea, you need a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) that uses next item in array every time it is invoked, something like this:

```
const current = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (current === arr.length - 1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  setStr(arr[current])
  current++;
}, 2000);
```

Of course you need to run it as an effect, keep the variables in a ref, clear interval on unmount etc.